# Check if only specific parameter is in URL

Tags: php, parameters, get

I want to display some content based on the parameter in the URL.

For example: I have a filter called **color**.

The URL looks like this:

> /?filter_color=**black**

Now I can add some content for the color black.

But now I have a problem with multiple active filter.

At the moment I also show the content for black if the URL looks like this:

> /?filter_color=**black**,**white**

But if there are multiple filter active I doesn't want to show any content.

Here's my current code:

```
if ( (isset($filter_color) == 'black') ) :

    echo 'content for black';

endif;
```

Is there any way to ask if it's ONLY the filter "**black**"?
I tried the following but that throws an error:

```
isset($filter_color) === 'black'
```

Comment: ___Big Note___ `isset()` returns a boolean, so TRUE or FALSE, so none of those tests make any sense

Comment: OK, but is there any way to check for a specific parameter?

Comment: `if( isset( $_GET['filter_color'] ) &&  $_GET['filter_color']=='black'){}` ??

Comment: Where and how is the data coming from? Or are you starting from scratch and want to build something?

Comment: The content comes from a custom post type. That's working already. Just need to check if I want the content or not.

Comment: Cray, see the answer below. strcmp will check if the string is exactly the same. strpos will check if it exists in the string.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner could you close the other question and let this one open? here's an answer. And sorry, didn't remebered that I already asked the same thing.

Comment: @Cray If you really feel that this isn't a repost, I'll reopen.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The other one was more about the meta title but that wasn't very clear in my question. So they sound very similar. I have to rewrite the other one I guess

Comment: @Cray I see. Okie dokie then. I reopened :) Sorry about that, I made a mistake.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks! I guess it was more my mistake ;)

Comment: You're welcome @Cray This was an honest mistake made. I should have asked you before I closed it and I apologize for it. I moved too fast on this one. Cheers

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check if a string is the same as another string**

If you want to check if a string contains ONLY a specific set of characters, you can use the `strcmp` or `strcasecmp`. strcasecmp is case *insensitive*.

```
if ( strcasecmp($filter_color, 'black') === 0) ) :
  echo 'content for black';
endif;
```

If the strings are the same the function will return 0. If the strings are different it will return either 1 (if the first string is greater than the second) or -1 (if the first string is less than the second).

**Check to see if a string contains another string (but could contain more):**

If you want to see if black is somewhere in the string, then you can use `strpos`. The first parameter is the string you are looking in, and the second is the string you are looking for. If it is found, it will return the location where it occurs in the string.

```
if ( strpos($filter_color, 'black') !== 0) ) :
  echo 'content for black';
endif;
```

*Be aware that if the string location is at the start of the string it will return 0. You must use === or !==*

Comment: It's kind of working but the content also shows if there is no filter at all!?